# Check value of numpy array at index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have recently started working in numpy. I am trying to test if a 2d array contains a specific subarray. The code below returns an error. How can I fix this?

```
import numpy as np

testArray = np.array([[None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0]])

for i in range(len(testArray)):
    if (testArray[i] == [None, 0]):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without iterating, you can use all:

```
>>> testArray[(testArray == [None,0]).all(1)]
array([[None, 0],
       [None, 0],
       [None, 0],
       [None, 0],
       [None, 0],
       [None, 0],
       [None, 0],
       [None, 0]], dtype=object)
```

Or if you just want to see whether that subarray exists, use `any` in addition:

```
>>> (testArray == [None,0]).all(1).any()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is a Value Error. When you compare the numpy arrays, you get an array consisting of boolean values. The problem was that you were using that array to as your condition, which resulted in the value error since the truth-value of arrays is ambiguous. You can resolve by using `.any` or `.all`, depending on whether you care if all the elements are present in your array.

Try this:

```
testArray = np.array([[None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0]]) 

for i in range(len(testArray)): 
    containsValue = (testArray[i] == [None, 0]).all()
    if (containsValue): 
        print(i)
```

Comment: You may as well be using lists, this doesn't use any numpy features. It will actually be slower than using lists.

Comment: They didn't ask to optimize for speed, they just said they had an error in their code.

Comment: Presumably they would not be layering in an external dependency to make their code _slower_ than native Python.

Comment: I can't pretend to know what the asker is thinking. They had an error in their code and my answer resolves said error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of your '[None, 0]' is a list which you are comparing to an array which doesn't make much sense.
So if you want to fix the code then you can access the values by:

```
import numpy as np

testArray = np.array([[None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0], [None, 0]])

for i in range(len(testArray)):
    if (testArray[i][0] == None and testArray[i][1] == 0):
        print(i)
```

Comment: As the other answer, there's absolutely no use for numpy in this approach

Comment: Where did they ask to use numpy in the approach?

Comment: It's a numpy array and they state that they're learning numpy?

Comment: one is a list the other one a numpy array, I will adjust my answer

Comment: He specifically stated that he is using numpy. I just fixed the code, I don't know why he wants to do it that way. But he never told us what he actually wants to achieve so, I do not know.

Comment: I am connecting dots and suggesting that the appropriate answer is one that makes use of vectorization. Treating numpy arrays as lists is almost always terrible performance. It's not unreasonable to assume that they are looking for improved efficiency by the fact they're using the library.

Comment: Might be true, but I believe he is just messing around with numpy to learn the stuff.